# videogular only showing black screen not playing the video

Tags: angularjs, html5-video, videogular

I have followed [this](http://www.videogular.com/tutorials/how-to-start/) page . and this is only showing black screen its not playing the video. 
here is my code

```
   vm.config = {
            sources: [
                {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"},
                {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.webm"), type: "video/webm"},
                {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.ogg"), type: "video/ogg"}
            ],
            tracks: [
                {
                    src: "http://www.videogular.com/assets/subs/pale-blue-dot.vtt",
                    kind: "subtitles",
                    srclang: "en",
                    label: "English",
                    default: ""
                }
            ],
            theme: "components/videogular-themes-default/videogular.css",
            plugins: {
                poster: "http://www.videogular.com/assets/images/videogular.png"
            }
        };
```

and HTML is

```
    <videogular vg-theme="vm.config.theme">
        <vg-media vg-src="vm.config.sources"
                vg-tracks="vm.config.tracks">
        </vg-media>
      </videogular>
```

my videoagular version is 
       `"name": "videogular",
       "version": "1.4.4",`
 and angular version is `"angular": "^1.5.0",`

Comment: It is not clear what is `vm` in your code! please use the exact code that is written in the reference.